Generating Clifford Circuits for Conjugating a List of Pauli Strings Into Another
Given two different sets of $2n$ $n$-qubit Pauli strings $A_0, A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{2n-1}$ and $B_0, B_1, B_2, \dots, B_{2n-1}$  with the promise that $[A_i, A_j] = [B_i, B_j]$ for all $i$, $j$, is it possible to generate the Clifford circuit which simultaneously conjugates $A_i$ into $B_i$ for all $i$? We can assume both sets are linearly independent, so that there is a unique Clifford operator which satisfies these conditions.
I am aware of tableau-style algorithms for similar tasks, such as the circuit synthesis algorithm in Section 7 of this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.13623) which describes a similar procedure for sets of $n$ operators instead of $2n$ operators by reducing any $n$-operator list to a canonical form. However, I'm not sure to what extent these techniques would generalize to the case where the number of operators exceeds the number of qubits.

The two sets of linearly independent Pauli operators, together with the preservation of commutators, indeed define a unique Clifford unitary. The logic is exactly the same as in linear algebra: Any two bases define a linear map mapping one into the other.
However, tableaus are defined with respect to the standard basis, $Z_1,\dots,Z_n,X_1,\dots,X_n$. In fact, they are simply a matrix representation in said basis. Hence, to explicitly obtain the Clifford unitary, and possibly a circuit representation of it, it is necessary to first compute the basis change matrices $M_A$ and $M_B$ that transform the $A$ and $B$ basis into the standard basis, respectively. This is simply done by writing the binary representation of the $A_i$ ($B_i$) into the columns of $M_A$ ($M_B$). The binary/tableau representation of the Clifford unitary is then given by $S=M_BM_A^{-1}$.
Note that this representation does not care about phases ($\pm 1$). This means that a Clifford unitary $U_S$ constructed from $S$ may only fulfill $U_S A_i U_S^\dagger = (-1)^{s_i} B_i$. To correct for that, find a Pauli operator $P$ such that $P B_i P^\dagger = (-1)^{s_i} B_i$. This can be done by solving a linear system of equations. Finally, $P U_S$ is the desired Clifford unitary.

Note this assumes the Pauli strings are linearly independent generators. If they aren't, then the given pauli strings can be contradictory (e.g. A0=A1 but B0!=B1) or underconstrained.

@Markus Heinrich Does the method you describe rely on the list of $A_i$'s ($B_i$'s) having the same commutation relations as the standard basis operators? In my use case, I don't have this guarantee.

@CraigGidney sure, but this was an assumption in Ben's question.

@BenFoxman no, it does not. If they would have the same commutation relations as the standard basis, the basis change matrices would be symplectic. But they can in fact be  arbitrary, and a brief calculation shows that the combination of both basis changes, i.e. $S$, is symplectic, so it corresponds to a Clifford unitary (up to Paulis). More generally, if you have a symplectic matrix $L$, you can represent it in some other basis as $M_B L M_A^{-1}$, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix#Symplectic_transformations

@BenFoxman Ah, that's right.
